# Подключение MySQL к Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mysql

Нашел в интернете информацию по подключению СУБД к Eclipse, объясняется доступно и в картинках, следуя по [этой инструкции](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Setup_MySQL_DB_in_Eclipse) наткнулся на проблему в 1 шаге:

по данному пути отсутствует пункт Data Source Explorer, поиск в Other не помог.

Использую Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли другие методы для подключения MySQL к Eclipse, или же у меня какие то проблемы с Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел даже больше, чем хотел найти: [JDBC Tutorial](http://www.javatalks.ru/ftopic7147/JDBC-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

В случае если у вас Maven проект:
качаем депенденси из Maven [репозитория](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)

Далее проверить установился ли драйвер можно написав следующий код

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("class found");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}